# Why does "123()" pass the ESLint test?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Type `123();` in [ESLint demo page](https://eslint.org/demo) and you'll pass the lint test.

Comment: Because it's a syntactically valid program. Run, `if (false) 123();` in a REPL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`123()` is syntactically legal javascript. If you run it you'll get a runtime error, but eslint doesn't check things at runtime, only at compile time. So the only way eslint would tell you there's a problem is if it violates one of the selected lint rules, which it evidently does not.

You could try creating a custom lint rule if this is something you need to check for. If the rule wants to be based on types, like a rule for "don't call numbers as functions", then I suspect it would be easier to create this rule if using typescript-eslint. But typescript can catch this out of the box without help from eslint, so a typescript-eslint rule wouldn't be much use.

Comment: Why this is syntactically legal?

Comment: I wondered that too. `123` doesn't match the expected format for identifiers so not sure why it parses OK?

Comment: Many of the things you can do with identifiers you can also do with literals. For example, it's legal to do `foo['bar']` to access the `bar` property of an identifier, and it's also legal to do `123['bar']` to access the `bar` property of a literal. Call expressions are another thing that work with both. You can make a call expression with an identifier, or with a literal. Whether or not this makes for *useful* code is a different matter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I got your point : )